# Regex to capture word before matched pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I tried to capture word before matched pattern. My search word is "ale". I have to get the word before `ale`

Input

```
"Golden pale ale by @KonaBrewingCo @ Hold Fast Bar",
```

I want `Golden pale` words only. Just to get words before matched pattern.

```
String pattern = "\w+\s" + "ale";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern); 
Matcher m = regex.matcher(stat);
if(m.find()){ Do something }
```

But it shows me error in Java. Anyone help please!!!

Comment: how many words do you want to capture before `ale`?

Comment: Do you mean you want a word before a word containing substring "ale" or a whole word "ale"? **See http://ideone.com/7qjSbq**.

Comment: You can convert a general regular expression as java regular expression with this web: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html You will avoid failures like escape characters.

Comment: @ rock321987 3 words to capture.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew Thank you so much, it helps me to find out. But, how to get three words before pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your search string should appear as part of another word, you need to add `\w*` before `ale`:

```
String keyword = "ale";
String rx = "\\w+\\s+\\w*" + keyword;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("Golden pale ale by @KonaBrewingCo @ Hold Fast Bar");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); // => Golden pale
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/7qjSbq)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric or underscore characters
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (`\W+` will match even punctuation, and other non-word chars)
- `\\w*` - zero or more word characters (optional part before ....
- `ale` - a literal character sequence.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works fine but how to get 3 words instead.

Comment: Please share an example string. Also, try [`String rx = "(\\w+\\s+){3}\\w*" + keyword;`](http://ideone.com/WcEhvH).

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew, For example" Drinking a Tribute Cornish Pale Ale by @staustellbrew", by the regex I got pale ale in this sample, if I want to get Cornish pale ale (I tried this regex "\\w+\\s+\\w*{0,3}"), but no luck.

Comment: You change the requirements. Now, you need to find the `ale` case insensitively as a whole word. See http://ideone.com/gADS6k. Please unify your specifications or use two different patterns and decide when to use which yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The character \ is an escape character.  You need to do something like this:

```
String pattern = "\\w+\\s" + "ale";
```